# RestKit 0.20 Ignore putObject: mapping

Tags: ios, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to send an object to the server (PUT request) without a mapping because I already have everything I need from the server. The callback directly goes to failure, even though the server has sucessfully created the object.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
- (void) PUTsuccess:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
             failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [YSManager objectManager];
    [objectManager putObject:self path:[kPutPath stringByAppendingString:self.id] parameters:kAPIDefaultParameters success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            NSLog(@"operation.HTTPRequestOperation.request.HTTPBody: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.HTTPRequestOperation.request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            if (success) {
                success(operation, mappingResult);
            }
        }
        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure! Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        if (failure) {
            failure(operation, error);
        }
    }];
}
```

The server response is 201 created and I can find back my object in the server so that's all good, but still, the callback directly fires failure because it's trying to map my object, the error in the failure callback is:

```
Error: No response descriptors match the response loaded.
```

Thanks a lot, any suggestion will be appreciated!

**Update 1**
Added dictionary mapping now:

```
RKObjectMapping *idMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [idMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[]];
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptorID = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:idMapping
                                                                                       pathPattern:[kRequestPath stringByAppendingString:@":code"]
                                                                                           keyPath:@"objects"
                                                                                       statusCodes:statusCodes];
```

Comment: Try using keyPath:nil and double-check the pathPattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a response descriptor simply to map the response (or part of it) to an NSDictionary.

Comment: Ok I now did this but the error I get now is: Error: No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched. See question for source code.

Comment: Sounds like the path pattern is correct but that the keypath of the descriptor is wrong. What's the response JSON?

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. Stupid me working late i guess... Thanks again!